# Dynamicly move rows between sheets - VB & Excel

Tags: excel, vba, google-apps-script

I am moving a project from Google sheets to MS Excel, in Google Sheets I have a function that move rows between different sheets based on a dropdown (on each row) containing the names of the sheets that you can to move the row to, this script work on all sheets, so you can move the rows back and forth between the sheets.
I got VB script to move a row from a specific sheet to another, but not dynamically between the sheets. Below is the working script for my google project, can anyone point me in the right direction for a VB script that do the same?

```
function onEdit4(e) {
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;
  if (r.columnStart != 2 || r.rowStart == 1 || e.value == src.getName()) return;
  const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(e.value);
  src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,22).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,22));
  src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
      }
```

Comment: "I got VB script to move a row from a specific sheet to another", why not [add it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73880595/edit) to your answer?

Answer (score 1):

I just try to guess the google way (c#?) and help to translate it to vba
Do you know anything about vba?

if r is a range and e is a range and src is a sheet (worksheet) then for the precheck:

```
if r.column <> 2 or r.row = 2 or e.value = src.name then exit function
```

For the copy and delete part

```
Sheets("a").Rows(7).Cut Sheets("b").Rows(11)
```

where Sheets("a") is your source sheet and Sheets("b") your destination sheet
Rows(7) is the row to cut you have to find your row number
Rows(11) is the destination row you have to find the last row +1 in the destination sheet, perhaps by CurrentRegion but I don't know your table construct

And last line should be

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

to end the cut copy mode